# \fbox inside listings

Tags: listings, boxes, highlighting, code

I am trying to highlight a specific line inside a listing with listinline. The code I am currently using looks like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=!]
class A {
  void m() {
    B b = ...
    !\fbox{b.n();}!
  }
}   
\end{lstlisting}
```

This works somewhat, however the text inside the `fbox` is obviously not processed by the listings package. Using `!fbox{\lstinline{b.n();}}!` produces an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that `listings` doesn't allow any verbatim code between two escape characters. One solution would be to store the `\lstinline{b.n();}` in a box outside the `lstlisting` and use the box inside it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
    \lstinline{b.n();}%
\end{lrbox}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=!]
class A {
  void m() {
    B b = ...
    !\fbox{\usebox\mybox}!
  }
}   
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a bit odd, because `!\verb|...|!` is allowed

Comment: @daleif: Yes, it is odd.

Comment: @MartinScharrer How can I do this but inside the Verbatim environment, and with an fbox containing several lines?

Comment: Put the `Verbatim` environment inside `lrbox` and a `minipage` environment and use `\fbox{\usebox\mybox}` again. You can also use my `adjustbox` package and wrap `Verbatim` with `\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,fbox} .. \end{adjustbox}`. Feel free to open a follow-up question if this doesn't help you enough.