# hf-tikz and references edges: draw in background?

Tags: tikz-arrows, overlays, hf-tikz

I have managed to draw this thing, which I find quite nice (sorry if it's not so minimal, but I tried to reduce it and having the same problem but it was a bit of a mess...):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz} 

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\splat}{\phantom{\bigg|}}
\begin{equation}
    H(\omega) = \frac{\vec{v_o}}{\vec{v_i}} = 
    \hfsetfillcolor{green!10}\hfsetbordercolor{green}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-c}(0,0.6)(0,-0.4)\frac{1}{10}\tikzmarkend{bp-c}\;\; 
    \frac
    {\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-z}(0,0.6)(0,-0.3) 1+j\splat\dfrac{\omega}{{10^6}}\tikzmarkend{bp-z}} 
    {\hfsetfillcolor{red!10}\hfsetbordercolor{red}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-p}(0,0.5)(0,-0.4) 1+j\splat\dfrac{\omega}{{5\cdot10^6}}\tikzmarkend{bp-p}} 
\end{equation}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm, height=9cm,
    xmode=log, 
    xmin=1e5,  xmax=1e9,
    domain=1e5:1e9, samples=200,
    ymin=-40, ymax=20,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50},
    xlabel = {angular frequency, $\omega$ (rad/s)},
    ylabel = {$||H(\omega)||$ (dB)},
    ytick = {-40,-20, 0, 20},
    legend style = {nodes=right},
]
    \addplot[thick, green] {-20};
    \addplot[thick, blue] {x<1e6 ? 0 : 20*log10(x/1e6)};
    \addplot[thick, red] {x<5e6 ? 0 : -20*log10(x/5e6)};
    \addplot[ultra thick, densely dashed, black] 
        {x<1e6 ? -20 : (x <5e6 ? -20 +  20*log10(x/1e6) : -20 +  20*log10(x/1e6) - 20*log10(x/5e6)};
        \legend{$1/10$, $1+j\omega/{10^6}$, $(1+j\omega/{5\cdot10^6})^{-1}$, total} 
    \coordinate (line-c) at (axis cs: 2e6, -20);
    \coordinate (line-z) at (axis cs: 2e6, 6);
    \coordinate (line-p) at (axis cs: 6e6, -2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture, overlay, draw opacity=0.5,>=latex, shorten >=4pt]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \path[red] (bp-p) ++(4em, 0) edge[thick, ->, bend left] (line-p);
        \path[green] (bp-c) ++(0.5em, 0) edge[thick, ->, bend left] (line-c);
        %%% this one should go in background
        \path[blue] (bp-z) ++(0,3ex) edge[thick, ->, bend right] (line-z);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the result here:

[image: Result of the (not-so-M)WE]

As you can see, I tried to use the technique in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24895/38080) to have the arrows (especially the blue one) in background, to no avail.

Is there an easy way to have the blue line going *below* the equation?

*PS*: I tried with `tikzmarks` [last release](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295987/38080), drawing  the arrows *before* the equation, but it seems that `hf-tikz` uses its own markers definition and they can be used only after definition. So I gave up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the pgflayers are locally to the current tikzpicture. So I think it is not possible to have the blue edge in the background of the equation. But I would change the path of this edge to not cross the equation. For example

```
\path[blue] (bp-z) ++(0,3ex) edge[thick, ->,out=175,in=150,looseness=2.5] (line-z);
```

results in

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz} 

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\splat}{\phantom{\bigg|}}
\begin{equation}
    H(\omega) = \frac{\vec{v_o}}{\vec{v_i}} = 
    \hfsetfillcolor{green!10}\hfsetbordercolor{green}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-c}(0,0.6)(0,-0.4)\frac{1}{10}\tikzmarkend{bp-c}\;\; 
    \frac
    {\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-z}(0,0.6)(0,-0.3) 1+j\splat\dfrac{\omega}{{10^6}}\tikzmarkend{bp-z}} 
    {\hfsetfillcolor{red!10}\hfsetbordercolor{red}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-p}(0,0.5)(0,-0.4) 1+j\splat\dfrac{\omega}{{5\cdot10^6}}\tikzmarkend{bp-p}} 
\end{equation}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm, height=9cm,
    xmode=log, 
    xmin=1e5,  xmax=1e9,
    domain=1e5:1e9, samples=200,
    ymin=-40, ymax=20,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50},
    xlabel = {angular frequency, $\omega$ (rad/s)},
    ylabel = {$||H(\omega)||$ (dB)},
    ytick = {-40,-20, 0, 20},
    legend style = {nodes=right},
]
    \addplot[thick, green] {-20};
    \addplot[thick, blue] {x<1e6 ? 0 : 20*log10(x/1e6)};
    \addplot[thick, red] {x<5e6 ? 0 : -20*log10(x/5e6)};
    \addplot[ultra thick, densely dashed, black] 
        {x<1e6 ? -20 : (x <5e6 ? -20 +  20*log10(x/1e6) : -20 +  20*log10(x/1e6) - 20*log10(x/5e6)};
        \legend{$1/10$, $1+j\omega/{10^6}$, $(1+j\omega/{5\cdot10^6})^{-1}$, total} 
    \coordinate (line-c) at (axis cs: 2e6, -20);
    \coordinate (line-z) at (axis cs: 2e6, 6);
    \coordinate (line-p) at (axis cs: 6e6, -2);
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[
    overlay, draw opacity=0.5,>=latex, shorten >=4pt]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \path[red] (bp-p) ++(4em, 0) edge[thick, ->, bend left] (line-p);
        \path[green] (bp-c) ++(0.5em, 0) edge[thick, ->, bend left] (line-c);
        %%% this one should go in background
        \path[blue] (bp-z) ++(0,3ex) edge[thick, ->,out=175,in=150,looseness=2.5] (line-z);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the code for the `background` layer is in the same `tikzpicture` environment as the `axis` to put the red arrow behind the legend.

---

As you suggested in a comment it is also possible to use a decoration to interrupt the blue edge. Using

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  continuous/.style 2 args={
    postaction={draw,solid, decorate,
      decoration={moveto,
        pre=curveto, pre length=#1*\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,
        post=curveto, post length=#2*\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance
}}}}
```

and

```
\path[blue] (bp-z) ++(0,3ex)edge[draw=none,thick, ->, bend right,
  continuous={0.08}{0.65}% first 8% and last 65%  are drawn
](line-z);
```

results in

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz} 

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  continuous/.style 2 args={%
    postaction={draw,solid, decorate,
      decoration={moveto,
        pre=curveto, pre length=#1*\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,
        post=curveto, post length=#2*\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance
}}}}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\splat}{\phantom{\bigg|}}
\begin{equation}
    H(\omega) = \frac{\vec{v_o}}{\vec{v_i}} = 
    \hfsetfillcolor{green!10}\hfsetbordercolor{green}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-c}(0,0.6)(0,-0.4)\frac{1}{10}\tikzmarkend{bp-c}\;\; 
    \frac
    {\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-z}(0,0.6)(0,-0.3) 1+j\splat\dfrac{\omega}{{10^6}}\tikzmarkend{bp-z}} 
    {\hfsetfillcolor{red!10}\hfsetbordercolor{red}
    \tikzmarkin{bp-p}(0,0.5)(0,-0.4) 1+j\splat\dfrac{\omega}{{5\cdot10^6}}\tikzmarkend{bp-p}} 
\end{equation}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm, height=9cm,
    xmode=log, 
    xmin=1e5,  xmax=1e9,
    domain=1e5:1e9, samples=200,
    ymin=-40, ymax=20,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50},
    xlabel = {angular frequency, $\omega$ (rad/s)},
    ylabel = {$||H(\omega)||$ (dB)},
    ytick = {-40,-20, 0, 20},
    legend style = {nodes=right},
]
    \addplot[thick, green] {-20};
    \addplot[thick, blue] {x<1e6 ? 0 : 20*log10(x/1e6)};
    \addplot[thick, red] {x<5e6 ? 0 : -20*log10(x/5e6)};
    \addplot[ultra thick, densely dashed, black] 
        {x<1e6 ? -20 : (x <5e6 ? -20 +  20*log10(x/1e6) : -20 +  20*log10(x/1e6) - 20*log10(x/5e6)};
        \legend{$1/10$, $1+j\omega/{10^6}$, $(1+j\omega/{5\cdot10^6})^{-1}$, total} 
    \coordinate (line-c) at (axis cs: 2e6, -20);
    \coordinate (line-z) at (axis cs: 2e6, 6);
    \coordinate (line-p) at (axis cs: 6e6, -2);
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[
    remember picture, overlay, draw opacity=0.5,>=latex, shorten >=4pt]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \path[red] (bp-p) ++(4em, 0) edge[thick, ->, bend left] (line-p);
        \path[green] (bp-c) ++(0.5em, 0) edge[thick, ->, bend left] (line-c);
        %%% this one should go in background
        \path[blue] (bp-z) ++(0,3ex)edge[draw=none,thick, ->, bend right,
          continuous={0.08}{0.65}% first 8% and last 65%  are drawn
        ](line-z);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was thinking.... what about some `decoration` trick to make the blue edge fully transparent between two given positions... Possible?

Comment: See my updated answer.