# tcolorbox: how to put shadow to whole box with boxed title?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, shadows

I'm working with `tcolorbox` to produce boxes and highlight answers to a document with questions.

The following MWE shows the box I created, separating the title into another box.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{resp}[1][]{%
    enhanced jigsaw,%
    colback=gray!20!white,%
    colframe=gray!80!black,%
    size=small,%
    boxrule=1pt,%
    title=\textbf{\textit{Answer}},%
    halign title=flush center,%
    coltitle=black,%
    breakable,%
    drop shadow=black!50!white,%
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},%
    minipage boxed title=3cm,%
    boxed title style={%
        colback=white,%
        size=fbox,%
        boxrule=1pt,%
        boxsep=2pt,%
        underlay={%
            \coordinate (dotA) at ($(interior.west) + (-0.5pt,0)$);
            \coordinate (dotB) at ($(interior.east) + (0.5pt,0)$);
            \begin{scope}[gray!80!black]
                \fill (dotA) circle (2pt);
                \fill (dotB) circle (2pt);
            \end{scope}
        }%
    },%
  #1%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{resp}
    An exciting text {\ttfamily:)}
  \end{resp}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \begin{resp}[boxed title style={drop shadow=black!50!white}]
    Another box with shadow {\ttfamily:/}
  \end{resp}
\end{document}
```

Result of compiling the above code:

[image: Result of compiling the above MWE code]

Thanks to the documentation, I could add a shadow to the text box (the one without the title), and as the second box shows, I could do the same with the second box. Unfortunately, the title box shadow overlaps with the text box, and I wanted it to be at the same level to the text box shadow (i.e. behind the text box).

How can I apply a shadow to both boxes as a group, so the shadows of both the title and the text box could be one, and behind the text box?

Comment: You want to have a 'halo', not a 'shadow' ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Mmmmm, that sounds good too, but what I mean with "shadow" is to also include the little one al the top right corner of the title box (see the second box of the MWE output picture).

Comment: Do you want to have the title box shadow outside of the title box, i.e. directed to 'north east'?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I hope I understood your question. If you mean to have the title box shadow as a separate entity, so I could place it behind the text shadow, yes. If not, I'm sorry: could you specify a bit, please? `:(`

Comment: The titlebox and the mainbox are drawn in two individual `tikzpicture`. Even if you apply `pgfonlayer` it will not help. But there is a workaround discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/installing-background-and-foreground-page-layers-with-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this? You can adjust the settings to improve the match. This is just an illustration of the method.

[image: box with title and shadow]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows.blur}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{resp}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=gray!20!white,%
  colframe=gray!80!black,
  size=small,
  boxrule=1pt,
  title=\textbf{\textit{Answer}},
  halign title=flush center,
  coltitle=black,
  breakable,
  drop shadow=black!50!white,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  minipage boxed title=3cm,
  boxed title style={%
    colback=white,
    size=fbox,
    boxrule=1pt,
    boxsep=2pt,
    underlay={%
      \coordinate (dotA) at ($(interior.west) + (-0.5pt,0)$);
      \coordinate (dotB) at ($(interior.east) + (0.5pt,0)$);
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (interior.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3ex]interior.east);
        \filldraw [white, blur shadow={shadow opacity=60, shadow yshift=-.75ex}, rounded corners=2pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}[gray!80!black]
        \fill (dotA) circle (2pt);
        \fill (dotB) circle (2pt);
      \end{scope}
    },
  },
  #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{resp}
  An box with a shadow {\ttfamily:)}
\end{resp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting `=)` That's a good trick. In fact, it comes in handy with blur shadows. But I have to ask: is it possible to do the same without the blur effect?

Comment: I got it. I only changed the clipping and rectangle positions as you said, and replaced the blur shadow with a drop one. Unfortunately, it seems `tcolorbox` uses a different rounded corners value _for shadows_ than the given ones for the size shorcuts. By the way, I didn't know `tikz` could handle clipping like CorelDRAW or Photoshop `:D`

Comment: @JBFWP286 Non-blur is actually standard. I just did it with blur to show that was possible too. Just load plain `shadows` for `drop shadow`. The blurred shadows sometimes look better. They sometimes look worse. And they occasionally look crazy ;). `toclorbox` uses `rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc` I think.