# Integrating a picture in a frame

Tags: floats, mdframed

I would like to make a frame using the package mdframed around a text and inside the frame I would like to integrate a small figure.
I attached an example created with another program (the figure is the picture of a small clock). I know how to do frames with latex but I do not know how to integrate the figure.
[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You should be able to do this with tcolorbox.

Answer (score 3):

I just made a quick search for tcolorboxes, found [this one by cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357054/121799), replaced the title text by some graphics and it immediately worked. Of course, you may drop the shadow, but I believe the shadow is unimportant for this to work. Generally, it is a good idea to do a google picture search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com` in it, very often you find an answer to your question almost immediately.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows.blur}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{resp}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=gray!20!white,%
  colframe=gray!80!black,
  size=small,
  boxrule=1pt,
  title={\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}},
  halign title=flush center,
  coltitle=black,
  breakable,
  drop shadow=black!50!white,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  minipage boxed title=3cm,
  boxed title style={%
    colback=white,
    size=fbox,
    boxrule=1pt,
    boxsep=2pt,
    underlay={%
      \coordinate (dotA) at ($(interior.west) + (-0.5pt,0)$);
      \coordinate (dotB) at ($(interior.east) + (0.5pt,0)$);
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (interior.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3ex]interior.east);
        \filldraw [white, blur shadow={shadow opacity=60, shadow yshift=-.75ex}, rounded corners=2pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}[gray!80!black]
        \fill (dotA) circle (2pt);
        \fill (dotB) circle (2pt);
      \end{scope}
    },
  },
  #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{resp}
  A cfr--made box with a shadow and some graphics as title.
\end{resp}
\end{document}
```

[image]