# Projected square magnified image using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy, pgflayers

Is there a way to achieve magnification like the one shown below using Spy library in TikZ? If so, how to achieve it? If not so, what better alternatives are there?

The thick yellow outlines below are not necessary. But I do want to achieve solid boundaries and dashed projection lines.

[image: magnification]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[spy using outlines={rectangle,magnification=4, size=2.5cm,connect spies}]
    \node[rectangle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=70px,height=70px]{image1.jpg}};
    \spy on (0,0) in node at (0,4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: my-magnification]

**UPDATE 1**

I managed to get the dashed square projection in the following way:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[spy using outlines={thick,red,rectangle,magnification=4, size=2.5cm,connect spies}]
    \node[rectangle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=70px,height=70px]{image1.jpg}};
    \spy[spy connection path={
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.north west) -- (tikzspyonnode.north west);
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south west) -- (tikzspyonnode.south west);
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.north east) -- (tikzspyonnode.north east);
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south east) -- (tikzspyonnode.south east);
}] on (0,0) in node at (1.5,3.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: my-magnification-2]

The only problem is that the dashed lines cross over the magnified image as you can see. How to send them behind?

**UPDATE 2**

If I use the `on background layer` as scope option, it did solve for the magnifying part, but then again these lines go behind the actual image:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[spy using outlines={thick,red,rectangle,magnification=4, size=2.5cm,connect spies}]
    \node[rectangle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=70px,height=70px]{image1.jpg}};
    \spy[fill=white,spy connection path={
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.north west) -- (tikzspyonnode.north west);
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south west) -- (tikzspyonnode.south west);
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.north east) -- (tikzspyonnode.north east);
    \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south east) -- (tikzspyonnode.south east);
    \end{scope}
}] on (0,0) in node at (1.5,3.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: my-magnification-3]

Comment: a MWE would be more than welcome as a starting point. Rewriting code from scratch is always a pain.... :)

Comment: Sorry my bad. I thought the basic code is pretty much straightforward and any image would do fine. But here, I have updated them.

Comment: So you're not happy with the single connector and want to get the 2 connectors as in your example. Right ?

Comment: No, this looks a bit boring. What I want to try is achieving the surface projection. Spy connection paths are dashed, and there should be 4 connections with corresponding points i.e north east to north east corner and so on. The magnified image should be on front layer while the spy connection lines are behind the magnified image.

Comment: Please see the update once more. I almost got what I wanted. But only a slight obstacle there.

Comment: Ah... it's actually another issue then. It's a question of layers ! :) Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/installing-background-and-foreground-page-layers-with-tikz). You want the magnified window to appear on the foreground vs the arrows.

Comment: For future reference, there are example pictures available out of the box, see `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738). This makes MWEs portable.

Comment: Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option using `intersections`:

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{scope}[spy using outlines={thick,red,rectangle,magnification=4, size=2.5cm,connect spies}]
            \node[rectangle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=70px,height=70px]{example-grid-100x100pt.jpg}};
            \spy[spy connection path={
                \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.north west) -- (tikzspyonnode.north west);
                \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south west) -- (tikzspyonnode.south west);
                \path[name path=Dline] (tikzspyinnode.north east) -- (tikzspyonnode.north east);
                \path[name path=SpyInBottomSide] (tikzspyinnode.south west) -- (tikzspyinnode.south east);
                \path [name intersections={of=Dline and SpyInBottomSide,by=I}];
                \draw[densely dashed,red](I) -- (tikzspyonnode.north east);
                \draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south east) -- (tikzspyonnode.south east);
            }] on (0,0) in node at (1.5,3.5);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This one's elegant! Thanks a lot! I wish there were easier options though to apply in general cases.

Comment: @J Leon V. I'm your click on the 10k :) nice !

Answer (score 5):

I would redraw the spy.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[spy using outlines={thick, red, rectangle, magnification=4, size=2.5cm}]
\node[rectangle, draw, inner sep=1pt] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=70px, height=70px]{example-image-duck}};
\spy[spy connection path={
\draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.north west) -- (tikzspyonnode.north west);
\draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south west) -- (tikzspyonnode.south west);
\draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.north east) -- (tikzspyonnode.north east);
\draw[densely dashed] (tikzspyinnode.south east) -- (tikzspyonnode.south east);
}] on (0,0) in node at (1.5,3.5);
\spy on (0,0) in node at (1.5,3.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Duck with extra magnified duck]

Comment: Aha! Nice way to hide the flaw there ha ha! This time ``connect spies`` are missing, didn't thought of that.