# Colored background in inline listings

Tags: listings, color, verbatim, sourcecode

I would like to make inline code more distinguishable from the text surrounding it, and I thought that using a background might work (like it is done on the stackexchange pages.)

Since I use the listings package for my other code samples, I tried the inline version of listings, but the key=value pairs seem not to work in the inline version (although the documentation seems to indicate that they should).

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
This is a test where \lstinline[backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}]{A=1} should have a yellow background.

This, on the other hand, actually works:
  \begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}]
    A = 1
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Questions:

1. Can it be done with listings? And how?
2. What other ways to
   increase the distinguishability of inline verbatim do you use?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice, for consistency, if color options worked in `\lstinline` as they work in the `lstlisting` environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not familiar with most of the color- and highlighting-related options of the `lstlistings` package. However, the `\colorbox` macro, which is defined in the `color` package and takes two arguments (the color and the item to be placed in the colored box), will do a nice job of highlighting a piece of inline text. The following MWE builds directly on your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,listings}
\begin{document}
This is to test whether \colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline{A=1}} 
has a yellow background.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: As [MartinScharrer has pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/colored-background-in-inline-listings#comment106239_28183), the `\colorbox` command won't get the job done if the argument of your `\lstinline` command contains "real" verbatim material -- which may well feature some TeX "special" characters such as `%`, `_`, `&`, and so on. For that contingency, you should load the [realboxes](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/realboxes) package and employ its `\Colorbox` macro:

```
This is to test whether \Colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline{A=@#$%^&*()1}} has a yellow background.
```

[image]

Comment: @xubuntix: Actually it doesn't work with real verbatim code, because you can't have it in an argument of another macro. E.g. replace `A=1` with `A=1%` and see how it breaks. You can however use `\Colorbox` from the `realboxes` package (requires `xcolor` too) which reads the content as a box, not as a macro argument.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\begin{document}
This is to test whether \Colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline{A=%1}} 
has a yellow background.
\end{document}
`

Comment: @MartinScharrer: is it possible to achieve the same effect just using `\lstinline` alone (without `\Colorbox`)? I use `xcolor`, define `\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}`, and `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines = true, backgroundcolor=\color{mygray}}`but I doesn't work for `\lstinline`. `This is \lstinline|my code|`.

Comment: @guest_5758 - May I suggest that you re-post your inquiry as a new question (possibly with a link to this older question)? That way, it'll b seen by lots or people. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico: okay, done. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357227/adding-background-color-to-verb-or-lstinline-command-without-colorbox

Answer (score 8):

You could also use the solution from [How to redefine \lstinline to automatically highlight or draw frames around all inline code snippets?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30845/how-to-redefine-lstinline-to-automatically-highlight-or-draw-frames-around-all/30851#30851)

[image]

The highlighting code is from [Highlight text in code listing while also keeping syntax highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/18890#18890)

### Known Issues:

- This is intended for use with *short* inline code snippets that do *not* span line breaks.

### References:

- See follow up question: [Problems at page boundaries trying to highlight `\lstinline`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124115/problems-at-page-boundaries-trying-to-highlight-lstinline)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{atbegshi,ifthen,listings,tikz}

% change this to customize the appearance of the highlight
\tikzstyle{highlighter} = [
  yellow,% set the color for inline listings here.
  line width = \baselineskip,
]

% enable these two lines for a more human-looking highlight
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\tikzstyle{highlighter} += [decorate, decoration = random steps]

% implementation of the core highlighting logic; do not change!
\newcounter{highlight}[page]
\newcommand{\tikzhighlightanchor}[1]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\coordinate (#1 highlight \arabic{highlight});}}}}}
\newcommand{\bh}[0]{\stepcounter{highlight}\tikzhighlightanchor{begin}}
\newcommand{\eh}[0]{\tikzhighlightanchor{end}}
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\ifthenelse{\value{highlight} > 0}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\foreach \stroke in {1,...,\arabic{highlight}} \draw[highlighter] (begin highlight \stroke) -- (end highlight \stroke);}}{}}}
%--------------------------


\makeatletter %   Redefine macros from listings package:
\newtoggle{@InInlineListing}%
\togglefalse{@InInlineListing}%

\renewcommand\lstinline[1][]{%
    \leavevmode\bgroup\toggletrue{@InInlineListing}\bh % \hbox\bgroup --> \bgroup
      \def\lst@boxpos{b}%
      \lsthk@PreSet\lstset{flexiblecolumns,#1}%
      \lsthk@TextStyle
      \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\afterassignment\lst@InlineG \let\@let@token}%
                         \lstinline@}%

\def\lst@LeaveAllModes{%
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@nomode
        \expandafter\lsthk@EndGroup\iftoggle{@InInlineListing}{\eh{}}{}%
    \else
        \expandafter\egroup\expandafter\lst@LeaveAllModes
    \fi%
    }
\makeatother


\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{green!10}}%


\begin{document}
This is a test where \lstinline{A=1} should have a yellow background.

This, on the other hand, actually works:
  \begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{green}]
    A = 1
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. However, when I used it at some pages there appear spureous highligths at places where there is not lstinline, or some highlights do not appear. Apparently what happens is that highlighs pertaining to a page appear in the previous page. This is related to highlights near the page break, and in combination with footnotes in the same page. Do you have a clue about why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: @JLDiaz: Added a _Known Issues_ to note that this won't work across line breaks (and also page breaks).

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not due to the code being too long. It is indeed a short snippet (`\lstinline!print!`), but it happens at the end of a paragraph which latex decided to break among pages, perhaps as a consequence of a footnote or, the starting of a new section after that paragraph or this kind of reasons. Apparently, the paragraph is broken _after_ the tikzmark is written in the aux file, and thus the information about the page in which should appear is wrong. If you want, I can post a new question with a MWE showing the problem.

Comment: @JLDiaz: Yeah, I think posting a new question makes sense.

Comment: Done: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124115/problems-at-page-boundaries-trying-to-highlight-lstinline

Comment: This is fantastic.  How great it must be to be capable of wizardry such as this.

Answer (score 0):

One could also declare a new command (or *document commant*) `\lsti`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

% The following doesn't work in all cases, as pointed out by matexmatics
% \newcommand{\lsti}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline|#1|}}

% This works in more cases, as pointed out by mbert
\NewDocumentCommand{\lsti}{v}{\colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline|#1|}}

\begin{document}
This is a test where \lsti|A=1| should have a yellow background.

It should also work with \lsti|A=1%| or \lsti|A={}| or \lsti|{{{|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work in all cases, as Martin Scharrer pointed out above: for example it does not work with `A=1%`.

Comment: If you replace with `\NewDocumentCommand{\lsti}{v}{\colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline|#1|}}` it should work

Comment: Thank you @mbert and matexmatics, I edited my answer.

Comment: Just a note, the new version also accepts syntax `\lsti|<code>|` so things like `\lsti|{{{|` work