# Different background colors for lstinline

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, color

In the following code, I've decided to use the code from [Colored background in inline listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/colored-background-in-inline-listings) so as to redefine `\verb` to have the possibility to use colors for the text and the background of the verbatim text.

The problem I meet is that only one color for the background can be used by page and I would like to have different background colors in the same page.

This is surely the consequence of the use of the style:

```
\tikzstyle{highlighter} = [%
    \bck@color, %
    line width = 0.9\baselineskip%
]
```

What are the changes to do in the following code?

Another question: is it possible to have a border rule with also a customizable color?

```
% Two compilations must be done !
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    % == EXTRA == %

    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

    % == PACKAGES USED == %

    \usepackage{xargs}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{atbegshi}
    \usepackage{ifthen}

    \usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \usepackage{listings}

    % == DEF : Verbatim with color option == %

    \definecolor{colorCodeNormal}{named}{black}
    \definecolor{colorCodeBack}{named}{Snow2}

    \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{colorCodeBack}}%

    \makeatletter
        \newcounter{highlight}[page]
        \newcommand{\tikzhighlightanchor}[1]{%
            \ensuremath{%
                \vcenter{%
                    \hbox{%
                        \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
                            \coordinate (#1 highlight \arabic{highlight});
                        }%
                    }%
                }
            }%
        }
        \newcommand{\bh}[0]{\stepcounter{highlight}\tikzhighlightanchor{begin}}
        \newcommand{\eh}[0]{\tikzhighlightanchor{end}}
        \AtBeginShipout{%
            \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{
                \ifthenelse{\value{highlight} > 0}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\foreach \stroke in {1,...,\arabic{highlight}} \draw[highlighter] (begin highlight \stroke) -- (end highlight \stroke);}}{}
            }
        }

        \newtoggle{@InInlineListing}%
        \togglefalse{@InInlineListing}%

        \renewcommand\lstinline[1][]{%
            \leavevmode\bgroup\toggletrue{@InInlineListing}\bh % \hbox\bgroup --> \bgroup
            \def\lst@boxpos{b}%
            \lsthk@PreSet\lstset{flexiblecolumns,#1}%
            \lsthk@TextStyle
            \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\afterassignment\lst@InlineG \let\@let@token}%
                \lstinline@}%

        \def\lst@LeaveAllModes{%
            \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@nomode
                \expandafter\lsthk@EndGroup\iftoggle{@InInlineListing}{\eh{}}{}%
            \else
                \expandafter\egroup\expandafter\lst@LeaveAllModes
            \fi%
        }

        \renewcommand\verb{%
            \@ifstar{%
                \lstset{%
                    showspaces=true,%
                    showtabs=true%
                }%
                \@verbItInColor%
            }{%
                \lstset{%
                    showspaces=false,%
                    showtabs=false%%
                }%
                \@verbItInColor%
            }%
        }
        \newcommandx\@verbItInColor[2][%
            1=colorCodeNormal,%
            2=colorCodeBack
        ]{%
            \ifx\relax#1\relax
                \edef\txt@color{colorCodeNormal}%
            \else
                \edef\txt@color{#1}%
            \fi
            \ifx\relax#2\relax
                \edef\bck@color{colorCodeBack}%
            \else
                \edef\bck@color{#2}%
            \fi
            \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{\txt@color}}%
            \tikzstyle{highlighter} = [%
                \bck@color, %
                line width = 0.9\baselineskip%
            ]
            \lstinline%
        }
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
% On this first page there is a problem.
\verb+NORMAL+

\verb[blue]+BLUE+

\verb[green][DarkViolet]+GREEN ON DARK VIOLET+ 

\verb[white][cyan]+WHITE ON CYAN+    

\newpage
% Here the background color is correct.
\verb[white][red]+WHITE ON RED+

\newpage
% Here again the backgorund color is the good one.
\verb[green][DarkViolet]+GREEN ON DARK VIOLET+

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying the same as my unfinished [`tikzpagenodes`](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/tikzpagenodes) package (uses [`tikzpagelayers`](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/tikzpagelayers), unfinished as well). While not complete finished, it should be usable for what you want to do. It stores settings internally for every page, so it would allow multiple colors per page. However, using this to add a background color for inline verbatim is overkill! There are better ways to do this.

Comment: Please state at the beginning what you are looking for. You are referencing another question and then show a lot of code. This makes it difficult to see what's *exactly* you are trying to achieve. For example are you want to use the syntax highlighting feature of `listings` or having a plain verbatim text like with the normal `\verb`? In the first case add some example line which actually uses some verbatim text which can be highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want some color background and/or frame around `\lstinline` you can do so with `\fcolorbox` from `xcolor` (or `\colorbox` if you don't need a frame). No need for TikZ and `atbegshi` tricks. One issue here is to put the verbatim material inside the macro, which is normally not allowed.

You can use `\Collectverb` from the `newverbs` package (not to be confused with `\collectverb`) to  collect the verbatim material in a form suitable to be passed to an internal `\lstinline` macro. This still won't allow `\lstinline` to alter any catcodes, but most characters should already have the ones required.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myverb[1][green]{%
    \@testopt{\@myverb{#1}}{-#1}% Handle second optional argument
}
\def\@myverb#1[#2]{%
    \Collectverb{\@@myverb{#1}{#2}}%
}
\def\@@myverb#1#2#3{%
    %\begingroup
    %\fboxrule=0.9\baselineskip
    %\fboxsep=...
    \fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\lstinline|#3|}%
    %\endgroup
}
\makeatother

% Usage:
% \myverb[<background color>][<frame color>]<char><content><char>
% or:
% \myverb[<background color>][<frame color>]{<content>}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C}
\myverb|int a = 1;|

\lstset{language=tex}
\myverb[yellow][green]{\relax % Just do it!}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the trick to collect the argument of the macro `\lstinline`.

Comment: The solution does not work inside footonote. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: I've noticed another very small problem. When I use `\lstset{showspaces=true, showtabs=true}`, all the tabulations become spaces. That's not really a problem.

Comment: @projetmbc: Again: You can't use verbatim inside other macros, this includes `\footnote`. You could try a `\cprotect\footnote` (`cprotect` package) which is written to allow verbatim material in arguments of other macros.

Comment: Also: never use tabs! Especially not in inline code. But if you want to display spaces or tabs try `\Collectverb*` instead of `\Collectverb`. As stated in the answer, `\lstinline` can't change the catcodes of the characters, so some option might not work fully.

Comment: The provided solution doesn't support listings' `mathescape` option: `\lstset{mathescape=true}` followed by `\myverb|$e$.f == 0|` causes the error (using `pdflatex`) `! Undefined control sequence.  \lst@arg ->$e`. Can `mathescape` be supported?

Comment: @MartinScharrer I get a `! File ended while scanning use of \@@Collectverb` if I do `myverb{some code}`.

Comment: @JonWong: Thanks for reporting this. The look-ahead code used to detect the optional argument apparently causes a problem with the `{`, so that `\Collectverb` does not find the matching closing brace. As a workaround use `\myverb|some text|` or another character for `|` not used in the text.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of redefining the internal of `\verb` you should define your own command.

In the following example I changed the implementation and use the benefits of the packages `xparse` and `newverbs`

*EDIT: Make the example more efficient -- Thanks @MartinScharrer*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newverbs}[2011/07/23]

\NewDocumentCommand \MyFrameVerb {m m m}
 {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle,fill=#2,line width = 0.9\baselineskip,font=\ttfamily,outer sep=0pt](tempa){#3};
      \draw[#1] (tempa.south west) rectangle (tempa.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
 }%
\NewDocumentCommand \myverb { O{gray} O{gray!25} }
 {%
  \collectverb{\MyFrameVerb{#1}{#2}}%
 }
\begin{document}

\myverb+NORMAL+

\myverb+NORMAL+

\myverb[blue]+BLUE+

\myverb[green][DarkViolet]+GREEN ON DARK VIOLET+ 

\myverb[white][cyan]+WHITE ON CYAN+    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use th lstinline in your code. I would like to have the possibility to put one background color and at the same time use the highlights made by listings.

Comment: I copied and pasted that example but it gives me the error on line 23 "Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the matht cause unrecoverable errors. \myverb+NORMAL+"

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is not true that your code allows to get just one background color for the whole document. Indeed, with this MWE:

```
% Two compilations must be done !
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% == EXTRA == %

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

% == PACKAGES USED == %

\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{listings}

% == DEF : Verbatim with color option == %

\definecolor{colorCodeNormal}{named}{black}
\definecolor{colorCodeBack}{named}{Snow2}

\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{colorCodeBack}}%

\makeatletter
    \newcounter{highlight}[page]
    \newcommand{\tikzhighlightanchor}[1]{%
        \ensuremath{%
            \vcenter{%
                \hbox{%
                    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
                        \coordinate (#1 highlight \arabic{highlight});
                    }%
                }%
            }
        }%
    }
    \newcommand{\bh}[0]{\stepcounter{highlight}\tikzhighlightanchor{begin}}
    \newcommand{\eh}[0]{\tikzhighlightanchor{end}}
    \AtBeginShipout{%
        \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{
            \ifthenelse{\value{highlight} > 0}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\foreach \stroke in {1,...,\arabic{highlight}} \draw[highlighter] (begin highlight \stroke) -- (end highlight \stroke);}}{}
        }
    }

    \newtoggle{@InInlineListing}%
    \togglefalse{@InInlineListing}%

    \renewcommand\lstinline[1][]{%
        \leavevmode\bgroup\toggletrue{@InInlineListing}\bh % \hbox\bgroup --> \bgroup
        \def\lst@boxpos{b}%
        \lsthk@PreSet\lstset{flexiblecolumns,#1}%
        \lsthk@TextStyle
        \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\afterassignment\lst@InlineG \let\@let@token}%
            \lstinline@}%

    \def\lst@LeaveAllModes{%
        \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@nomode
            \expandafter\lsthk@EndGroup\iftoggle{@InInlineListing}{\eh{}}{}%
        \else
            \expandafter\egroup\expandafter\lst@LeaveAllModes
        \fi%
    }

    \renewcommand\verb{%
        \@ifstar{%
            \lstset{%
                showspaces=true,%
                showtabs=true%
            }%
            \@verbItInColor%
        }{%
            \lstset{%
                showspaces=false,%
                showtabs=false%%
            }%
            \@verbItInColor%
        }%
    }
    \newcommandx\@verbItInColor[2][%
        1=colorCodeNormal,%
        2=colorCodeBack
    ]{%
        \ifx\relax#1\relax
            \edef\txt@color{colorCodeNormal}%
        \else
            \edef\txt@color{#1}%
        \fi
        \ifx\relax#2\relax
            \edef\bck@color{colorCodeBack}%
        \else
            \edef\bck@color{#2}%
        \fi
        \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{\txt@color}}%
        \tikzstyle{highlighter} = [%
            \bck@color, %
            line width = 0.9\baselineskip%
        ]
        \lstinline%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb+NORMAL+

\verb[blue]+BLUE+

\verb[green][DarkViolet]+GREEN ON DARK VIOLET+ % on this page there is the problem

\verb[white][cyan]+WHITE ON CYAN+    
\newpage
% here the background color is correct
\verb[white][red]+WHITE ON RED+
\newpage
% here again
\verb[green][DarkViolet]+GREEN ON DARK VIOLET+

\end{document}
```

allows you to get 3 pages with 3 different background colors.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my question.