# \lstinline & \colorbox

Tags: macros, symbols, listings, color

Why the command below don't work? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    morekeywords={RequirePackage,ProvidesPackage,NeedsTeXFormat},
    backgroundcolor=\color{background}
}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\newcommand*{\inlinecode}[1]{%
                            \colorbox{background}%
                            {%
                            \lstinline!#1!%
                            }
                            }

\begin{document}

ipsum dolor sit amet \inlinecode{%\@#&\newcommand=_^*} ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `\lstinline` inside arguments is experimental (see Section **5.1 Listings inside arguments** of the listings documentation) and can easily break; a modification of **Martin Scharrer**'s answer to [Different background colors for lstinline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51038/3954) can be used to solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\definecolor{keywords}{HTML}{8A4A0B}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    texcsstyle=*\color{keywords},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    morekeywords={RequirePackage,ProvidesPackage,NeedsTeXFormat},
    backgroundcolor=\color{background}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\inlinecode[1][background]{%
    \Collectverb{\@inlinecode{#1}}%
}
\def\@inlinecode#1#2{%
    \colorbox{#1}{\lstinline|#2|}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\inlinecode|\@#&\newcommand=_^*|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The provided solution doesn't support listings' `mathescape` option: `\lstset{mathescape=true}` followed by `\inlinecode|$e$.f == 0|` causes the error (using `pdflatex`) `! Undefined control sequence.  \lst@arg ->$e`. Can `mathescape` be supported?