# Inline code with background color without use of escape characters

Tags: color, listings, inline

I need to include some inline code in a text with a background color. I use `\lstinline` for including code in a text and `\colorbox` for making a background color for it.

`\lstinline!$!` produces `s` (without gray background) and `\colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{\lstinline!$!}` produces `s`. `\lstinline!\(!` produces `\(` (without gray background). This is everything as I need.

**But there is a problem:**

When I use `\colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{\lstinline!\(!}` it produces only `(` instead of `\(`. I found the solution and use `\colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{\lstinline!\\(!}` to produce `\(`. So, there is a need to use an escape character.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to include some inline code with background color (I need to use at least svgnames or some with more collors) in a text without to worry about the need to use escape characters in inline code?

---

Complite code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstinline!$!

\colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{\lstinline!$!}

\lstinline!\(!

\colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{\lstinline!\(!}

\colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{\lstinline!\\(!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: like most verbatim commands `\lstinline` can not be used in the argument of another command

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there some other way to include some inline code with background color (I need to use at least svgnames or some with more collors) in a text without to worry about the need to use escape characters in inline code?

Comment: you can not in general escape characters to make it work, it simply doesn't work. You can use the `\lstinput` form and input the code fragments from files, or you could use the lrbox environment to typeset the listing in a box and then colour the box, or I think the tcolorbox package as some options to make the interface a bit easier.

Comment: also https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=background+color+listings

Comment: Found interesting examples here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51038/different-background-colors-for-lstinline