# Background color in inline code listings with linebreak

Tags: listings, color, line-breaking

I want to highlight code inline with a gray background. Preferably with `listings`.
This question is related to [Colored background in inline listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/colored-background-in-inline-listings).

But as my MWE shows it doesn't work with line breaks. Is there a way to fix this? I also tried the soul package, but this produces a lot of errors (comments in MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\lstdefinestyle{ShellCmd}{
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    linewidth=0.9\linewidth,
    breaklines=true
}
\def\ownstrut{\vrule height5.5pt depth0.8pt width0pt}

\newcommand\shellcmd[1]{\colorbox{gray!10}{\lstinline[style=ShellCmd,mathescape]`#1`}}
%\newcommand\shelltwo[1]{\hl{\lstinline[style=ShellCmd,mathescape]`#1`}} % this produces error

\begin{document}

\shellcmd{command}, some text \shellcmd{a very long command which should not destroy the whole layout when a line break occurs! Maybe it is possible to make even three or more lines}, and here it continues. 
%\shelltwo{a very long command which should not destroy the whole layout when a line break occurs! Maybe it is possible to make even three or more lines}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To abuse soulregister as explained here seems to work:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\colorbox{}` is a box, that means you can't have a newline inside.

You can try to use `\parbox` but that will also not do what you want (see `\shellthree`).

You can solve your problem with package `soul` and `\texttt` as shown at the last three lines in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor,showframe}
\usepackage{soul}

\lstdefinestyle{ShellCmd}{
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    linewidth=0.9\linewidth,
    breaklines=true
}

\newcommand\shellthree[1]{\colorbox{gray!10}{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\lstinline[style=ShellCmd,mathescape]`#1`}}}


\begin{document} 

\lstinline[{backgroundcolor=\color{gray!50}}]{Testzeile testzeile testzeile}
\lstinline[style=ShellCmd]{Testzeile testzeile testzeile}

Command some text \shellthree{a very long command which should not destroy the whole layout when a line break occurs! Maybe it is possible to make even three or more lines}, 
and here it continues. and here it continues and here it continues and here it continues 

\colorlet{hellgrau}{gray!10}
\sethlcolor{hellgrau}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \texthl{\texttt {text highlight with soul}}.

\end{document}
```

I use package `soul`, change the color with `\colorlet`, set the color with `\sethlcolor` and use `texthl{texttt{}}` to set the text. This works also for line breaks.

Comment: no shellthree doesn't look much better ;) so there isn't a way to combine soul and lstinline?

Comment: I think thats way beyond my capabilities in TeX ^^ Maybe I wait some days an then accept your answer if it is still the only one :)