# How to make \hl (highlighting) to automatically place incompatible commands in \mbox?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, highlighting, soul

The `soul` package provides a useful command `\hl` for highlighting text.
However, `\cite`, `\ref`, and some other commands (maybe equations too) must be placed within an `\mbox` in order for `\hl` to work properly.

Is there any way to make this automatic? Meaning that to modify `\hl` (and other commands provided by `soul`) to put everything except plain text in an `\mbox`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\section{1}\label{sec}
This is to show that \textbackslash{hl} fails to highlight texts containing citations or reference!

\hl{ This is one line containing a citation \mbox{\cite{}}}

\hl{ This is one line containing a reference \mbox{\ref{sec}}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Really interesting question, but I guess a counter question is necessary: how can you tell all those commands which are incompatible?

Comment: @Sean, good question! So far I have noticed that `\cite`, `\ref` and some inline equations are incompatible. Putting everything except a plain text in a `\mbox` would not be a good idea since some commands need text wrapping! For a preliminary solution, maybe defining a list of incompatible commands and automatically place them inside an `\mbox` (if they are used in `\hl`) would help!

Comment: Maybe with `\soulregister\ref{7}`?

Comment: Thanks, Yes indeed, it was quite helpful! 
By using `\soulregister\X{7}`, where `X` is the command name, `\hl` encloses that command in braces.

Comment: This is really only useful if you use numeric citation and never use the optional argument to \cite. Anything longer, like author-year format will eventually cause a serious H&J problem.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can (ab)use `\soulregister` with the identifier `7`. While this command is meant to be used to register font switching commands (with identifier `0` or `1`), a look in the implementation part of the documentation reveals that it also accepts other numbers: `9` for accents, `8` for `\footnote` and, the one that's interesting here, `7` for "`\textsuperscript` or similar commands". Obviously, `\cite`, `\ref` and friends are similar enough.

When a command is registered this way, `soul` will first expand it (including the argument), and then feed the result as a whole to its scanner, just like `\mbox` would do. Note that while this is good enough for highlighting, striking out and underlining, it also means that it won't work in letterspaced text - there's no error, but no letterspacing either (which, I would guess, is probably the reason why these commands are not registered by default).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\pageref7
\begin{document}
\st{This is a line containing a citation \cite{}.}

\hl{This is a line containing a reference \ref{sec} on page \pageref{sec}.}

\so{This reference: \ref{sec}, is not letterspaced.}

\setcounter{section}{122}
\section{1}\label{sec}
\end{document}
```

[image: soul output]

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer! I found out that if `\xspace` is defined this way, it won't function well.

Comment: I'll add for the sake of others like me who found this to work half-way: if you're using `\citep` or `\citet`, you'll need to add a line for each: `\soulregister\citep7` and `\soulregister\citet7`.

Comment: Or one can use {} like {\ref{sec}}. This doesn't require to use \souregister\ref7 command :-D

Comment: Can this be modified to allow prefix/suffix options of \citep? For example, `\hl{Things were said \citep[e.g.,][]{author2016}.}`, which renders as "Things were said (?)e.g.,][]author2016".

Comment: @jbaums not with reasonable effort, I'm afraid. You'll have to put these citations in an `\mbox`.

Comment: Ohhh, YES !!!!!

Comment: This doesn't really work for e.g. citations which have a line break (the highlighting spills outside the line), whereas `\mbox{\textcite{citation}}` would.

Answer (score 14):

Another option using curly braces `{}` around `\ref, \cite` or `\pageref`commands may be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul,color}

\begin{document}
\st{This is a line containing a citation {\cite{}}.}

\hl{This is a line containing a reference {\ref{sec}} on page {\pageref{sec}}.}

\so{This reference: {\ref{sec}}, is not letterspaced.}

\setcounter{section}{122}
\section{Section \# 123}\label{sec}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice & simple solution.

Comment: does not work for me. same bug

Comment: @kevinkayaks It works with me without a problem. What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but I learned it works with `\citep{person2018}` but not with `\citep[e.g.,][]{person2018}` which (unfortunately for trackchanges) is a construction I often use.

Comment: I'm getting `Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.`

Answer (score 0):

Now that the LaTeX 3 programming layer and `xparse` have become part of LaTeX, another option is using regular-expression replace.  I think, this should be as robust as manually placing incompatible commands in `\mbox`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, soul, xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% comma-separated list of commands that require protection
\clist_const:Nn \l_soul_protect_clist { cite , citep , ref , eqref }
\NewDocumentCommand{\robusthl}{m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % replace \cmd with \mbox{\cmd} for all \cmd in the
  % list of protected commands (\l_soul_protect_clist)
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_soul_protect_clist {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{##1}[^{}]*\{[^{}]*\}) } %
                           { \c{mbox}\{\1\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  }
  \hl\l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Start Here}
\label{sec:start-here}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \robusthl{(see
  Section~\ref{sec:start-here})}, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
%
\robusthl{Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
  felis~\cite[et al.]{lamport94, lamport94}.}

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd Edition, 1994.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: A screenshot of the output with highlighted \ref and \cite]

It might be possible to apply this fix to a macro shared by the different `soul` commands so that it automatically also works for strikeout and underline, but I have not explored this yet.