# Extra spaces problem when using soul package combined with cite package to highlight citation

Tags: citing, soul, cite-package

When I use the `soul` package combined with the `cite` package to highlight some text that contains tilde and citation (e.g. `\hl{Ref.~\cite{xyz}}`, I get unwanted extra space between the word "Ref." and the citation number.

[image]

I put tilde here because I don't want LaTeX to interpret the dot as the end of the sentence.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\usepackage{cite} % error disappears without this package


\begin{document}
\hl{Ref.~\cite{xyz}}

Ref.~\cite{xyz}
\end{document}
```

Here, I have used `\soulregister\cite7` as suggested in [How to make \hl (highlighting) to automatically place incompatible commands in \mbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in)

I need the `cite` package to contract `[1,2,3,4]` to `[1-4]` (I don't have this in MWE, but I do in my actual document).

Comment: I get the same space with and without the `\hl`. Does your MWE really show the behaviour on your system? Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes you're right. Thanks. I forgot to add `\usepackage{cite}` in my MWE. Now it has been added. I need this package to contract [1,2,3,4] to [1-4].

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks for your suggestion. I've implemented in my MWE.

Comment: I shortened your MWE a bit, as the important part was not clearly visible. Also note, that you may delete everything about dot and tilde as well. `Ref \cite{x}` will result in the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the tilde but the fact that the package `cite` seems to check for missing white space in front of the citation. With `cite` loaded, `A \cite{x}`, `A~\cite{x}`, and `A\cite{x}` result in the very same. All of them get one white space in front of your `[<number>]`.

The error we are getting now, is that `cite` seems to have problems in finding leading white space inside the `\hl{}` command. It does not find any and adds it every time. Therefore, an easy workaround would be to put the `\cite` command always directly behind the word `Ref.`. This saves you from typing tildes as well.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\usepackage{cite}


\begin{document}
\hl{Ref.\cite{xyz}}

Ref.\cite{xyz} % cite adds the correct white space here

Ref. \cite{xyz} % cite converts the white space to a tilde

Ref.~\cite{xyz} % everything done manually
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: another possibility: load `cite` with the `noadjust` option to disable its handling of spaces before a cite

Comment: Hi @LaRiFaRi I see. Thanks for the explanation on how `cite` package handles white space before citation.