# soul package \hl with \cite gives error: "@citex has an extra }"

Tags: errors, soul

The following MWE gives me an error. This should work, shouldn't it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\hl{A statement \cite{hong_groups_2004}}
\end{document}
```

Here's the error:

```
! Argument of \@citex has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.4 \hl{A statement \cite{hong_groups_2004}}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139463/7674

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try enclose `\cite{hong_groups_2004}` in an extra pair of curly brackets (`{}`), without  those, [soul](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul) may do funny things with the `\cite`-command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\hl{A statement {\cite{hong_groups_2004}}}
\end{document}
```

Section 2.1 and 2.2. in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf) describes some problems and possible solution. In addition, I suggest that you use the more robust [soulutf8](http://ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8) by Heiko Oberdiek to avoid possible future errors. With [soulutf8](http://ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8), it is possible to use `utf8`, which is a must if you use other languages than US English.

New MWE:

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{color,soulutf8}

\begin{document}
\hl{A statement {\cite{hong_groups_2004}}}

Normal text.

\hl{Highlighted text with æøåÆØÅ}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** If the additional pair curly brackets (`{}`) does not solve the error, try to enclose the command in a `\mbox{}` instead, i.e. `\mbox{\cite{hong_groups_2004}}`.

My best tip is to read the manual subsection 2.3.1 to see if you recognise some of the borderline cases described there. This may give you some hints regarding possible solutions.

Comment: This solution gets rid of the citex error, but creates a new one: ! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

Comment: @elplatt I found putting `\protect` before the citations is a decent solution.

Comment: @kevinkayaks. It partially works. I have a command called `replace` which changes the color and strikes the text. In the text I have two citations. Using project before the two of them makes it compile, which is great! BUT only the text color is applied to the entire text. For some reason the strike style is applied only until just before the first citation.