# Define a command that uses \st and can be used to wrap text containing \cite{...} macros

Tags: macros, citing, natbib, cite-package

Using `natbib` together with `hl` or `st` from `soul` (or `soulutf8`) produces `Argument of \@citex has an extra }. [{\st\cite]` errors, as already mentioned in [other questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310817/30481).

While a solution is to wrap all the `\cite` commands with an additional pair of curly brackets, or when this fails with `\mbox`, this solution may not be very convenient.

Consider in particular the situation in which we have a document, in which for some reason we are forced to use `natbib` for the references (like what happens when using `revtex` document classes).
We have lots of text with lots of `\cite` in it.
We want to define a command `\remove` that highlights text to be removed, with something like `\newcommand{\remove}[1]{{\color{red}\st{#1}}}`.

To use this command in blocks of text containing lots of `\cite` can be very annoying, requiring to wrap all of them with brackets or `\mbox`.
Is there a way to define a "smarter" command that can be used over `\cite` without modifying the original text?

---

A MWE of the problem of using `\hl` and `\cite` together is already given in the linked question, but I'll include another just for completeness:

Tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{natbib}

% how can I more smartly define this command, to use it to wrap text containing \cite{...}?
\newcommand{\remove}[1]{{\st{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\remove{\cite{foo}}

\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@article{foo,
 author = {SomeGuy},
 journal = {Somewhere},
 title = {Foo}
}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139463/7674, I'd say. Answer: `\soulregister\cite7`

Comment: @Robert yep! that worked perfectly, thanks for link

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `\sout` from package `ulem` works.

Comment: well, this seems to indeed be the case, thanks for reporting! The `\st` command from `soul` still seems to work slightly better (look for example at how the G is handled in the two), but this definitely a quick work around. I would still be interested to know if there is a way to make `soul` work in this context though