# Why does \cite command does not work inside \add or \hl commands...?

Tags: errors, citing, soul

Why does `\cite` command not work inside `\add` or `\hl` commands...?

If my sentence goes like...

1. `\cite{Brown2015} studied so and so things` and I wish to highlight the citation, so I would modify `\hl{\cite{Brown2015}} studied so and so things.` But this does not work!
2. `\cite{Brown2015} studied so and so things` and I wish to add another citation `\cite{grey2015}` so that I would modify `\cite{Brown2015} \add{and \cite{gray2015}} studied so and so things.` But this does too not work!

Can anyone help! Where am I wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to your question? Currently, your issue is hard to reproduce.

Comment: Related questions regarding the `\cite` command inside of `\hl`: [How to highlight citations in a revised manuscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335992/134144), [How to make \hl (highlighting) to automatically place incompatible commands in \mbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139463/134144) and [soul package \hl with \cite gives error: “@citex has an extra }”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310817/134144) To summarize: Surrounding the `\cite` command with an extra pair of `{}` as in `\hl{{\cite{<yourcitationkey>}}}` should work.