# How to highlight text containing citation and figure referencing?

Tags: color, highlighting, soul

I am trying to highlight a text with reference. Without references, the below works fine. Could anyone know how to handle the highlighting the text containing citation and figure references? MWE is given below. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{%
    \colorlet{foo}{#1}%
    \sethlcolor{foo}\hl{#2}}%
}



\begin{document}

\hlc[pink]{hello given by mattsson et al \cite{mattsson1998physical}}

\hlc[cyan!50]{hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you might find an answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in/139500

Comment: @sheß: \hlc[green!50]{The write-up is given and please see the figure \mbox{\ref{fig1}}}. In place of \ref{fig1}, use \cite{mattsson1998physical}.  The key is using \mbox to wrap the figures and cites. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The soul package (`\usepackage{soul}`) provides `\hl` command for highlighting text. But, `\cite`, `\ref` are not compatible with `\hl` and must be placed within an `\mbox` in order for `\hl` to work properly. An `\mbox` also lets soul see the contents as one item.

You can use the `\mbox`.

```
\hl{\mbox{\cite{roohani2019numerical}}
```

At the same time if you want to highlight the reference in the bibliography list, you have to annotate the reference within bibliography file. For instance:

```
@article{roohani2019numerical,
title={\hl{Numerical study and sensitivity analysis on convective heat 
transfer enhancement in a heat pipe partially filled with porous material 
using LTE and LTNE methods}},
author={\hl{Roohani Isfahani, Seyed N and Salimpour, Mohammad R and Shirani, 
Ebrahim}},
journal={\hl{Heat Transfer—Asian Research}},
volume={\hl{48}},
number={\hl{8}},
pages={\hl{4342--4353}},
year={\hl{2019}},
publisher={\hl{Wiley Online Library}}
}
```

For more information you can refer to soul package documentation:
[soul package documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/special/soul.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been looking for something like `\mbox{}` and couldn't recall what it was called.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `lua-ul` package for highlighting. This way you don't have to worry about citations or cross-references in your text:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {{Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie}},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\highLight[red]{hello given by mattsson et al \cite{einstein} and Figure~\ref{fig}.}

\highLight[green]{hello}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the soul package (`\usepackage{soul}`), and make the reference or the citation between curly braces inside of the `\hl` command:

```
\hl{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur dictum {\cite{your citation}} or {\ref{your reference}} gravida mauris.}
```

Comment: [Cicilio's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543691/277964) already explains how to use `soul` and `\hl` and also explains how to solve the issue using `\hl` with `\cite`. So IMHO this unfortunately is not really a useful new answer.

Comment: @cabohah The `{...}` approach seems to have not yet been covered in the other answer and might actually be more flexible in certain situations.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The only difference here is, that instead of `\mbox` only braces are used. Sorry, but IHMO this is at most a comment to the existing answer than a new one.