# How to use \discretionary inside soul's \hl?

Tags: hyphenation, highlighting, nesting, soul

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
    Some \hl{te\discretionary{-}{-}{-}xt}.
\end{document}
```

The above does not compile due to *Missing { inserted*, *Improper discretionary list*, *Incompatible list can't be unboxed* and *Improper \prevdepth* errors. Removing `\hl` or `\discretionary` removes all errors.

How can I fix the code to allow nesting of `\discretionary` in soul’s `\hl`?

---

### Update:

I would like to locally redefine `\discretionary` to return just its third argument, as the original command would not work within soul’s macros. I managed to go up to this point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}%\usepackage{color}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139500:
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\pageref7

\def\highlightcolor{yellow}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlc}[2][\highlightcolor]{{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{{\renewcommand*\discretionary[3]{\mbox{####3}}#2}}}}

\begin{document}
    \hlc{Some,te\discretionary{-}{-}{-}xt}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this still throws error if highlighted text contains spaces. I think it is caused by double braces in `\hl{{…}}`, but I was unable to redefine `\discretionary` within `\hl`’s scope in other ways. Are there some alternatives to allow text highlighting without removing `\discretionary` commands – I have quite long pieces of text containing such commands that I need to highlight, but in the final version the highlighting is to be removed. So I do not want to remove `\discretionary` commands, but just to locally redefine them to something not causing errors when highlighting is in use. Returning just its third arguments would be enough for me.

Comment: you can't. \discretionaries are in the "don't work" list of soul, see the documentation.

Comment: `soul` uses `\discretionary` for its inner working, so redefining it is out of question.