# Soul hl within a mdframed environment won't print footnote number?

Tags: footnotes, mdframed, soul

I am trying to highlight some text with `soul::hl` within a `mdframed` environment defined by `newmdenv`. I get expected output using:

- hl text outside of the environment
- normal text within the environment.

However, when I try highlighted text within the environment, the number of the footnote disappears... not sure why?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
]{action}

\begin{document}

This is some normal text\footnote{text}.
\hl{This is some highlighted text\footnote{text}.}

\begin{action}
This is some normal text\footnote{text}.
\end{action}

\begin{action}
\hl{This is some highlighted text\footnote{text}.}
\end{action}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible work-around is `\soulregister\footnote7` (see also [How to make \hl (highlighting) to automatically place incompatible commands in \mbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139463/263192))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\footnote7 % <--
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
]{action}

\begin{document}

\begin{action}
This is some highlighted text\footnote{text}.
\end{action}

\begin{action}
\hl{This is some highlighted text\footnote{text}.}
\end{action}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, thanks!!