# LaTeX; how to color-highlight footnotes?

Tags: color, footnotes

I'm trying to highlight a footnote in a paper.    However, using xcolor/colorbox seems to break the formatting, as the attached minimal example should illustrate.   There must be a fix or alternative?   (Just removing "\colorbox{yellow}" restores the correct formatting, but at the expense of the required highlighting, of course.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Hello world\footnote{\colorbox{yellow}{This is a highlighted footnote
    that is intended to occupy only one column, but which actually
    runs across -- and beyond -- two columns when highlighted using
    ``colorbox''.}}.

\end{document}
```

[In reality, the text is in two-column format, and the footnote also contains (natbib) references, which seems to break the soul package.   But those observations are just for info, and incidental to the main problem.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `soul` package and the command `hl{}`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
Hello world\footnote{\hl{This is a highlighted footnote
            that is intended to occupy only one column, but which actually
            runs across -- and beyond -- two columns when highlighted using
            ``colorbox''.}}.
    
\end{document}
```

Works with `pdflatex`

For the natbib ref, there is a solution see the comment below.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in , you need to add this in the preambule : `\soulregister\cite7`  to tell soul not to expand the argument when it is `cite`.

Comment: Actually, i'd started with this solution, but soul had broken on two counts (the citations, and also a "\newcommand" text definition).   However, your supplementary comment pointed me at what  turns out to be the very straightforward workround of just putting problematical items into \mboxes.   Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can basically do this : `soulregister\anycommandthatyouwant7` . Finally, if you use any utf8 characters, there is the  `soulutf8` package.

Answer (score 4):

Without `lualatex` underlining and highlighting is a world of pain.

Use `lua-ul` and `luacolor` and your life will be much easier:

```
% TeX Program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Hello world\footnote{\highLight{This is a highlighted footnote that is
intended to occupy only one column, but which actually runs across -- and
beyond -- two columns when highlighted using ``colorbox''.}}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I'd been locked in to pdflatex, but this  worked nicely.   Sorry i can't mark both your reply and anis' as an accepted answer, as your solution worked just as well as his.   Thanks!