# How do I combine `\lit` with `\hl`?

Tags: highlighting

If I have the following:

`` \lit*{\char`\\ b} ``

How do I combine this with a `\hl` (highlight) to get a highlighted version of `\b`?

(`\lit` is from the `syntax` package, and `\hl` is from `soul`)

Comment: Where are `\lit` and `\hl` defined?

Comment: @egreg Seems that `\lit*` is from the `syntax` package, and probably `\hl` from the `soul` package. But it's better if the OP can confirm that.

Comment: @quark67 Yep, sorry for not clarifying - those are the corresponding packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me is usually to change how soul registers the command you are inputting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}
% \usepackage{xcolor} % for colouring
\usepackage{soul}

\soulregister\lit7 % this tells soul to register \lit as non expanded command.
% so the result is \hl{result of lit}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    Example

    \lit{Example}
    
    \hl{Example}
    
    \hl{\lit{Example}}
\end{document}
```

For more details: [How to make \hl (highlighting) to automatically place incompatible commands in \mbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in)

### Edit

According to quark67's comment, you can create a new command `\newcommand{\newlit}[1]{\lit*{#1}}` as register that one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for colouring
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\newlit}[1]{\lit*{#1}}
\soulregister\newlit7 % this tells soul to register \newlit as non expanded command. Yes the 7 at the end is what does it!
% so the result is \hl{result of \lit*}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    Example

    \lit{Example}
    
    \hl{Example}
    
    \hl{\lit{Example}}

    \hl{\newlit{Example}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: by extending this reasoning, you can register any command that `hl` will take as an argument, like `cite`.

Comment: Very good solution. I suggest that you expand your solution to more closely match the OP's request. In the preamble, create a new command (as I'm unable to \soulregister the starred version on \lit directly): `\newcommand{\newlit}[1]{\lit*{#1}}`. Then \soulregister it: `\soulregister\newlit7`. Then in the document, use "\hl{\newlit{\char`\\ b}}" (and probably uncomment the line "\usepackage{xcolor}" as the OP probably would use "\hl" with a colored background.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, you can modify the comments "register \lit" -> "register \newlit"  and "so the result is \hl{result of lit}" -> "so the result is \hl{result of \lit*}" to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @MingPokNg if you accept the answer, please validate it.