# Colored box around sentences

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to have a colored box around the text/sentences and its width will be fixed to be 80% of the page width. I tried `\fcolorbox` but it can't break lines. It is possible to do it with *TikZ* or is there a handy package available? Thx!

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out the posting [Colored background in inline listings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28179/5001)? The immediate issue raised by the posting is about coloring an inline *listing* text string, but the solutions provided to that question, which involve the `\colorbox` command, apply more broadly.

Answer (score 11):

with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.73,0.56,0.64}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=myviolet,
    width=.8\textwidth,   % this option controls the width of the box
    colupper=white,
    fontupper=\bfseries
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
   Example
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It seems that an answer with `mdframed` is missing. Here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.73,0.56,0.64}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[%
    rightmargin=.2\textwidth,
    backgroundcolor=myviolet,
    linewidth=0pt,
    fontcolor=white%
]{mybox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mybox}
Example
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Solution Idea**

In order to break lines, we can use `minipage` environment inside a [`\colorbox`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Entering_colored_background_for_the_text).

---

**The Solution**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\medskip

\colorbox{Lavender}{
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}
    \large\color{White}\lipsum[2]    
  \end{minipage}}

\medskip

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

---

**Output**

[image]

---

**Limitation**

Can not handle page breaks.

Comment: a bit of extra space between the end of the box and the following text would look better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your input. Noticed that, did not bother since the basic solution was there. Updated anyway. You can never ignore the looks :-)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to give what you want, at least as long as you do not need pagebreaks (for such needs look at the framed or mdframed packages):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,textwidth=15cm,textheight=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\noindent\colorbox{Thistle3}{\parbox{\dimexpr 0.8\textwidth -2\fboxsep\relax} {\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}Example.  Example. Example.  Example. Example.  Example.  Example.  Example.}}

\end{document}
```

[image]