# How to make frame around text with background color

Tags: tables, formatting, framed

I was trying to achieve this but unable so any help appreciated thanks.
[image]

This is the code I tried:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\centering

\scalebox{.8}

{
    \begin{tabular}{>{\center}p{10cm}}

                \framebox[10cm]{Some text here} \\
                \framebox[10cm]{\{Some text here\}} \\
                \framebox[10cm]{Some text here} \\
                \framebox[10cm]{Some text here} \\
                \framebox[10cm]{Some text here} \\
                %\framebox[8cm]{\colorbox{BlueGreen}{Some text here}} \\
                %\colorbox{BurntOrange}{Some text here} \\

    \end{tabular}
}
\caption{User registration phase of proposed scheme}
\label{fig:User registration phase}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You might be interested in [Colored box around sentences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151467/134144)

Comment: can't get desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the `tcolorbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=#2pt,
    colback=#1,
    width=10cm,
    halign=center,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{mybox}{green}{0}
     Some text
  \end{mybox}
  \begin{mybox}{white}{1}
     some text
  \end{mybox}
  \begin{mybox}{yellow}{0}
     some text
  \end{mybox}
  \begin{mybox}{white}{1}
     some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
  \end{mybox}
\caption{User registration phase of proposed scheme}
\label{fig:User registration phase}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```