# Adding background color to \verb or \lstinline command without \Colorbox

Tags: listings, color, verbatim, sourcecode

### Update:

In addition to my previous post, here's a screenshot to give you a better visual example. This was created with `HTML` and `CSS` for demo only.

In `CSS`, the `code` part is made using `font-family: monospace, sans-serif;`, `background: #EFF0F1;`, `display: inline-block;`, and `padding: 2px 5px;`.

I wonder if there's a **simple** way to mimic this style in `LaTeX` using `\lstinline` (or better options) **without** `\Colorbox` (if possible). All instances of `\lstinline` would have the same style.

What I mean by **simple** is that I thought I could just write something (once) inside `\lstset{}` in the preamble--which is simple--rather than typing `\Colorbox` in every instances of `\lstinline`--which is long and awful for a novice like me. Otherwise, using `\Colorbox` would be just fine.

[image: sample image]

### Original question:

I need to create `inline codes` with gray background using either `\verb` or `\lstinline`. I've read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/colored-background-in-inline-listings/28183?noredirect=1#comment106240_28183) which use `\Colorbox` which works great!

**My question**: Could we achieve the same effect just using `\lstinline` alone, without `\Colorbox` so it would be more simple?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines = true,
backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\begin{document}

% demo using \lstinline only
This is \lstinline|my code|

% demo using \lstinline and \Colorbox
This is \Colorbox{mygray}{\lstinline|my code|}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want all instances of `\listinline` to be colored automatically, or should the coloring be performed only for select instances?

Comment: @Mico: I'd prefer all instances of `\lstinline` be automatically colored. I just posted an update above.

Comment: Which TeX engine do you use at present? If yo're not already using LuaLaTeX, would switching to LuaLaTeX be feasible?

Comment: @Mico I'm using `PDFLatex` right now. Never had enough experiences with another engines. I'd tried `XeLaTeX` for a few times and learned `KOMA-Script` (which I still don't really understand), but never use `LuaLaTeX` before. To be honest, I don't know exactly the differences among those engines, but I think switching-over would be just fine..

Comment: Glad to learn that you're willing to give LuaLaTeX a try :-), as I just revised my answer to show how to set up a preprocessor function, using Lua code, to automatically encase all instances of `lstinline|...|` in `\Colorbox` wrappers.

Answer (score 15):

You can patch `\lstinline` to use `\Colorbox`; of course you lose the possibility to break lines in `\lstinline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{realboxes}

\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\lstinline{\Colorbox{mygray}\bgroup\appto\lst@DeInit{\egroup}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstinline[language=TeX]|\my code|

\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX]
\my code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The vertical size of the box depends on whether there are any descenders or ascenders in the text.  Is there a more elegant way to make the box always have the same vertical height than what I did, which is to add the term `\vphantom{ly}` to the patch?  Secondly, I'd like to make the extra padding of the box around the text a little smaller, is there a way to achieve this?  Maybe closer to the vertical and horizontal padding of the `lstlisting` code section

Comment: I've created a new question about reducing the padding of the `Colorbox` macro at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408878

Answer (score 13):

(I rewrote this answer after the OP indicated that he/she was mainly interested in having all instances of `\lstinline` colored *automatically*, i.e., without having to encase the instances in explicit `\Colorbox{<color-of-choice>}{\lstinline...}` "wrappers".)

To the best of my knowledge, the `listings` package currently does not offer an option or setting for rendering all instances of `\lstinline...` against a colored background. If you are willing and able to use LuaLaTeX -- and, who knows, maybe you're already doing so -- it is straightforward to set up a Lua function that acts as a pre-processor, i.e., scans all input lines at a very early stage of processing and automatically encases all instances of `\lstinline|...|`, `\verb|...|`, and `\Verb|...|` in `\Colorbox{mygray}{...}` wrappers.

In the example code below, it is assumed that the 'arguments' of `\lstinline`, `\verb`, and `\Verb` are *always* delimited by `|` ("pipe") symbols. To suspend the action of the Lua function, either use different delimiter symbols or execute the macro `\ColorLstinlineOff`.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings,realboxes,fancyvrb} % fancyvrb for '\Verb' macro
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines = true, backgroundcolor=\color{mygray}}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} % just for this example

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
-- the following code employs Lua's powerful "string.gsub" function
function color_lstinline ( s )
   s = string.gsub ( s , "\\lstinline%b||", "\\Colorbox{mygray}{%0}" ) 
   s = string.gsub ( s , "\\[vV]erb%b||", "\\Colorbox{mygray}{%0}" ) 
   return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% Define 2 LaTeX macros to switch operation of Lua function on and off
\newcommand{\ColorLstinlineOn}{\directlua{
   luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
   color_lstinline, "color_lstinline" )}}
\newcommand{\ColorLstinlineOff}{\directlua{
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
   "color_lstinline" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\ColorLstinlineOn} % Default: activate the Lua function 

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
This is my \lstinline|amazing| code.
This is my \verb|@#$%^&*()\%| code.
This is my \Verb!amazing! code. 
This is my \Colorbox{mygray}{\lstinline!amazing!} code.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great! That long codes look scary though. A bit more complicated compared to `\Colorbox` 's approach, but works great. Plus, since I'm new to `LaTeX`, I have to learn more about this engine and figure out how big are the differences compared to another engines. On the other hand, `\Colorbox` is simpler in this case, except that I have to type in every instances of `\lstinline` manually which could be possibly missing. I know both has it's own pros and cons. Nevertheless, I think I could just copy-paste the codes (instead of typing manually), right?

Comment: @guest_5758 - Glad this works for you. :-) Indeed, you should fee free to simply copy-and-paste the lines from `\usepackage{luacode}` to `\AtBeginDocument{\ColorLstinlineOn}` into the preamble of your document and not have to worry about `\Colorbox` any longer.

Comment: @guest_5758 - I've just edited the Lua code so that it also treats instances of `\verb` and `\Verb` the `\lstinline` gets treated.  (`\Verb` is a macro provided by the `fancyvrb` package.)

Answer (score 3):

The following defines a new macro `\clist` (needs package `xparse`) which automatically approaches the colorbox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines = true,
backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
}
\usepackage{realboxes}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\clist}{v}{%
    \Colorbox{mygray}{\csname lstinline\endcsname!#1!}%
}

\begin{document}

% demo using \lstinline only
This is \lstinline|my code|

% demo using \lstinline and \Colorbox
This is \Colorbox{mygray}{\lstinline|my code|}
\clist{my code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I may have misunderstood the OP's objective, but I thought it was to avoid using `\Colorbox`. (You may or may not agree with this objective...) If my understanding is correct, encasing `\Colorbox` inside a new macro (called `\clist`) probably won't help achieve the OP's objective.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I should have written `avoid using \Colorbox`...

Comment: 1. Does this mean that If I use this method I should not use `\Colorbox` elsewhere with different arguments? 2. Is the same true for `\colorbox` and `\lstinline`?

Comment: @vasili111 (1) No, that's absolutely unrelated. (2) Without having researched it, I would say yes.

Comment: @TeXnician What does `avoid using \Colorbox` means in previous comments? I am new to LaTeX and it is very hard to understand what exactly code does. Anything I should be aware of using the code above?

Comment: @vasili111 No, not really. The comment just meant that I did understand the OP differently (I thought he just did not want to write it every time).

Comment: This approach fails when intending to place the `\clist` command in tabularx-environments.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to create an alias for the grey background when you want it

```latex
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{mygray}{\lstinline|#1|}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This approach fails when the code contains braces. ... you could escape them, but the point of lstinline is that you should not have to