# Adjust the padding provided by Colorbox macro from the realboxes package

Tags: boxes, highlighting

My goal is to use the `Colorbox` macro from the `realboxes` package to highlight inline code with the `lstinline` command from the `listings` package.  The `Colorbox` command works great for this purpose, except that I find the amount of padding around the box to be a little too big for my tastes.  Below I present a MWE and show the compiled example, and then show a comparison of what I would like it to look like (the modified version was created using image manipulation software).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{realboxes}

\begin{document}
Some inline code \Colorbox{gray!20}{\lstinline{@#$%^&*()}} here
\end{document}
```

Actual:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can locally set a different value for `\fboxsep`; in order to have all those backgrounds the same height, a phantom seems the best solution. You can also reduce the padding on the sides by using kerns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{realboxes}

\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\lstinline
  {%
   \bgroup\fboxsep=1.5pt
   \Colorbox{mygray}\bgroup\kern-\fboxsep\vphantom{\ttfamily\char`\\y}%
   \appto\lst@DeInit{\kern-\fboxsep\egroup\egroup}%
  }{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\lstinline[language=TeX]|\my code| \lstinline|axe| \lstinline|lll|

\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX,columns=fullflexible]
\my code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I use this code with the `microtype` package, I've discovered that text in the inline blocks starting with a `+` or `-` shifts horizontally left slightly out of the background box.  In other words, an entry such as `\lstnline{-n}` will result in the box  surrounding the `-n` text to be in the correct place, but the `-n` itself moves left.  Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Comment: Very nice. I found that inserting ``\let\Scalebox\relax`` right before ``\usepackage{realboxes}`` fixed an error I was getting, probably caused by some other package (re)defining ``Scalebox``.

Answer (score 7):

It uses the same `\fboxsep` parameter as the standard `\colorbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{realboxes}

\begin{document}
Some inline code \Colorbox{gray!20}{\lstinline{@#$%^&*()}} here

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
Some inline code \Colorbox{gray!20}{\lstinline{@#$%^&*()}} here
\end{document}
```