# \newcommand: command wrapped around another

Tags: macros

Real simple one — how do you define `\codemath{...}` to do `\text{\lstinline{...}}`?

I've tried the following so far:

```
\newcommand{\codemath}{\text\lstinline}        % does nothing
\newcommand{\codemath}{\text \lstinline}       % does nothing
\newcommand{\codemath}{\text\ \lstinline}      % works, but with extra space

\newcommand{\codemath}{\text{\lstinline}}      % does nothing
\newcommand{\codemath}{\text{\lstinline}       % error
\newcommand{\codemath}{\text\{\lstinline}      % works, but with extra {
```

---

*I've seen a lot of questions about "wrapping", "multiple arguments", and "nesting", none of which have helped me. Neither has [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands).*

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Many verbatim-type environments require explicit in-line positioning of the ending marker in order to terminate the environment.  (Think about it.)  I believe that `lstinline` may be such an environment.  In that case, what you request would be impossible.  This should be confirmed (or demonstrated to be wrong) by someone who actually uses `lstinline`.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape from math mode by using `\hbox\bgroup` and using `\lst@DeInit` for issuing the closing `\egroup`.

The trick comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357339/4427

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\codemath}{%
  \leavevmode % just in case this sneaks out of math mode
  \hbox\bgroup
  \appto\lst@DeInit{\egroup}%
  \lstinline
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
a+\codemath|x+y|\int
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The code runs and is displayed correctly, but I still get a LaTeX error (warning?) that says *Command \ttfamily invalid in math mode...please use the math alphabet \mathtt instead of the \ttfamily command*. Can I ignore this safely?

Comment: Another issue: when `\codemath` is wrapped with  `$$ \begin{cases} ... \end{cases} $$`, the following two errors and produced: *Missing } inserted* and *Extra }, or forgotten $*.