# Markdown to pdf with pandoc : how to get color for code framed by a single back-tick

Tags: color, code, backgrounds, markdown

To print `.md` to `.pdf` I use pandoc. (due to many contributor in this forum. Thx to them)
**problem** = I would like to have (in the pdf) the same background color for the code no matter if I use triple backtick or simple backtick 
eg: 
**`** code surrounded by one backtick = no background color **`** 
but 
**```** `code with tree backticks = background color OK` **```**

I'm a noob in Latex, if I could get some help...

**my settings**

- My Command :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pandoc "$1" \
    --include-in-header inline_code.tex \
    --include-in-header listings-setup.tex \
    -V linkcolor:blue \
    -V geometry:a4paper \
    -V geometry:margin=2cm \
    -V mainfont="DejaVu Serif" \
    -V monofont="Space Mono" \
    --listings \
    --pdf-engine=xelatex \
    -o "$2"
```

- the file `listings-setup.tex`used with `--listings`

```tex
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    extendedchars=true
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{248,197,196},
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=fixed,
    frame=trbl,
    frameround=tttt,
    framesep=7pt,
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}},
```

- the file `inline_code.tex`

```tex
\definecolor{Light}{HTML}{F4F4F4}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
  \colorbox{Light}{\oldtexttt{#1}}
}
```

Easier to understand my broken english with a picture :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the option `--listings` pandoc uses `\lstinline` for inline code (not `\texttt`), so you have to patch `\lstlinsting`. You can do so with egreg's code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357339/29873). The code below *replaces* the code in your `listings-setup.tex` (you don't need `inline_code.tex` anymore, since it's all done with listings):

```
\usepackage{xpatch,realboxes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Light}{HTML}{F4F4F4}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    extendedchars=true
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{248,197,196},
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=fixed,
    frame=trbl,
    frameround=tttt,
    framesep=7pt,
    breaklines=true, postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}}
}


\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\lstinline{\Colorbox{Light}\bgroup\appto\lst@DeInit{\egroup}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Now call

```
pandoc infile.md \
    --include-in-header listings-setup.tex \
    -V linkcolor:blue \
    -V geometry:a4paper \
    -V geometry:margin=2cm \
    -V mainfont="DejaVu Serif" \
    -V monofont="Space Mono" \
    --listings \
    --pdf-engine=xelatex \
    -o outfile.pdf
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: 2. I have supposed code you wrote was to replace my code in the file "listengs-setup.tex", so i did. I got a grey rectangle at the begining of the inline code and lost my hookrightaroww caracter.
I feel this very cloth to what i need but still need to ajust the configuration.

Comment: 3. > so you have to patch \lstlinsting. You can do so with egreg's code here:

I'm lost : "patch ``lstlinsting`" how i do that ? The post of egreg does't help is difficult to understand.

Comment: 1. > With the option --listings pandoc uses \lstinline for inline code (not \texttt)

I have changed `texttt` by `lstinline` in the file "inline_code.tex". is it correct ?

Comment: So: You don't need "inline_code.tex" anymore, just use "listings-setup.tex" with the code I posted in my answer.

Comment: It works ! And this is what I was asking for. Thanks !
But this cannot manage long line any more, hookrightarrow disappeared and the text goes until the limit of the page before making a second line bigining at left limit of the page (just for inline code, block code is still ok). [2021-02-01-06h43-15.png](https://postimg.cc/CRWP8DY7)  
This is another story... I can break my lines in the code and find the solution to that later. Latex seems very touchy...
Thanx again for your help.

Comment: Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.

Comment: Done. Thanks for this explanation