# How do I highlight single lines of code?

Tags: listings, packages, highlighting, code

This is the listing that I have created. I want to highlight eg. lines 8,9 and 10. Using and escaped `\colorbox`  didnt work to my expectations because it altered the style of the code making the font smaller thus messing up the alignment of the code.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines,caption=Output of disassemble main]
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x08048344 <main+0>:    lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
0x08048348 <main+4>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x0804834b <main+7>:    pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
0x0804834e <main+10>:   push   %ebp
0x0804834f <main+11>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048351 <main+13>:   push   %ecx
0x08048352 <main+14>:   sub    $0x10,%esp
0x08048355 <main+17>:   movl   $0x57,-0x10(%ebp)
0x0804835c <main+24>:   movl   $0x3,-0xc(%ebp)}
0x08048363 <main+31>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048366 <main+34>:   add    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048369 <main+37>:   mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
0x0804836c <main+40>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x08048371 <main+45>:   add    $0x10,%esp
0x08048374 <main+48>:   pop    %ecx
0x08048375 <main+49>:   pop    %ebp
0x08048376 <main+50>:   lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
0x08048379 <main+53>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.


\end{lstlisting}
```

Is there a package where I can comfortably tell it to highlight some lines  I feed into it ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting?

Comment: I am quite new to latex, so I cant quite follow through with the answers

Comment: there surely has to be an easier way of doing this, right ?

Comment: none of the provided answers from the other threads work, without breaking the compilation or the style of the document

Comment: Then you should ask a new question which clearly shows what you want (best with picture) and what you have tried (as *full* MWE, meaning with documentclass etc.). You could also edit this question and then try to reopen it.