# Why is this way of highlight text in code listing not working with beamer class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, listings, highlighting

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15257/18401) provides a nice solution to [Highlight text in code listing while also keeping syntax highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15237/18401) which is improved in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18890/18401). The point is the former works like a charm with the `beamer` class but, as shown by the following MCEs, not the latter (nothing is highlighted).

How to make the latter solution work with `beamer`?

(Note that other answers, e.g. [this nice one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49309/18401), provide solutions that are working with `beamer`.)

### Former answer which is working with `beamer`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,tikz}
\newcommand\bh{\tikz[remember picture]
  \node (begin highlight) {};
}
\newcommand\eh{\tikz[remember picture]
  \node (end highlight) {};
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[yellow,line width=10pt,opacity=0.3] (begin highlight) -- (end
  highlight);
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\bh abc bce bde bde \eh

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@,language=SQL]
WHERE name=@\bh@UNION SELECT@\eh@
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Latter answer which is *not* working with `beamer`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% required packages
\usepackage{atbegshi,ifthen,listings,tikz}

% change this to customize the appearance of the highlight
\tikzstyle{highlighter} = [
  yellow,
  line width = \baselineskip,
]

% enable these two lines for a more human-looking highlight
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\tikzstyle{highlighter} += [decorate, decoration = random steps]

% implementation of the core highlighting logic; do not change!
\newcounter{highlight}[page]
\newcommand{\tikzhighlightanchor}[1]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\coordinate (#1 highlight \arabic{highlight});}}}}}
\newcommand{\bh}[0]{\stepcounter{highlight}\tikzhighlightanchor{begin}}
\newcommand{\eh}[0]{\tikzhighlightanchor{end}}
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\ifthenelse{\value{highlight} > 0}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\foreach \stroke in {1,...,\arabic{highlight}} \draw[highlighter] (begin highlight \stroke) -- (end highlight \stroke);}}{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
Works in \bh{}plain text too\eh{} (but not across line breaks).

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@, language=SQL, basicstyle=\sffamily, columns=fullflexible]
SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE name='@\bh@' UNION SELECT "10", 1 #@\eh@';
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When you say that the second method works also in plain text, why is the output not highlighted?

Comment: @marmot Sorry, it's not my claim, but the one from the author of the original solution (which works indeed in plain text for the `article` class but not for `beamer`) that I reproduced verbatim. Is is worth editing the question in order to avoid the confusion?

Comment: I see. And your question is not to repair the code (as there are already plenty of working alternatives) but really why it does not work, right?

Comment: @marmot Indeed.

Comment: I *guess* what is going on is that beamer uses its own shipouts, and the additional one ends up on a lower layer. The fact that the code compiles when you do not load `atbegshi` supports this. But I guess only @samcarter can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@marmots analysis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420116/why-is-this-way-of-highlight-text-in-code-listing-not-working-with-beamer-class/421856#comment1051646_420116) of the problem was correct. The highlighting in the second example works perfectly fine, it is just below the background layer. If you change the background colour from its default `white` to `empty` you can see the highlighting:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% required packages
\usepackage{atbegshi,ifthen,listings,tikz}

% change this to customize the appearance of the highlight
\tikzset{highlighter/.style={
  yellow,
  line width = \baselineskip,
}}

% enable these two lines for a more human-looking highlight
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\tikzstyle{highlighter} += [decorate, decoration = random steps]

% implementation of the core highlighting logic; do not change!
\newcounter{highlight}[page]
\newcommand{\tikzhighlightanchor}[1]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\coordinate (#1 highlight \arabic{highlight});}}}}}
\newcommand{\bh}[0]{\stepcounter{highlight}\tikzhighlightanchor{begin}}
\newcommand{\eh}[0]{\tikzhighlightanchor{end}}
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\ifthenelse{\value{highlight} > 0}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\foreach \stroke in {1,...,\arabic{highlight}} \draw[highlighter] (begin highlight \stroke) -- (end highlight \stroke);}}{}}}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
Works in \bh{}plain text too\eh{} (but not across line breaks).

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@, language=SQL, basicstyle=\sffamily, columns=fullflexible]
SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE name='@\bh@' UNION SELECT "10", 1 #@\eh@';
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]